# How to convert a continues stream of images to h264 stream in realtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, ffmpeg, webrtc

So basically I have a canvas, that keeps updating itself at a framerate of 24, and I would like to convert the sequence of images that it produces to H264. The ultimate goal is to send it to an RTMP server, but for now this will help me check if things are working properly before piping the output. The canvas API that I'm using (see [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas)) allows me to capture a JPEG of the entire canvas surface at any given moment. Unfortunately, the input will only be submitted once I end the STDIN, which is not what I want. Instead of processing all the input in a batch, I would like to process incoming JPEGs as I go, so everything can be done live. This is the code snippet that I used to achieve the functionality in question (which unfortunately doesn't work):

```js
// patches/canvas.js
const { Canvas } = require('canvas');
const execa = require('execa');
const $ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');

Canvas.prototype.captureStream = function captureStream(frameRate = 24) {
  const refreshRate = 1000 / frameRate;

  const encoding = execa($ffmpeg, [
    '-f', 'image2pipe',
    '-r', frameRate,
    '-vcodec', 'mjpeg',
    '-s', `${this.width}x${this.height}`,
    '-i', '-',
    '-vcodec', 'libx264',
    '-preset', 'veryfast',
    '-crf', '18',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-b:v', '500k',
    '-bufsize', '600k',
    '-vprofile', 'baseline',
    '-tune', 'zerolatency',
    '-g', '60',
    '-r', frameRate,
    '-s', `${this.width}x${this.height}`,
    '-f', 'rawvideo',
    '-',
  ], {
    stdio: 'pipe',
  });

  let lastFeed = Date.now();

  const feed = () => {
    const jpegStream = this.jpegStream();

    jpegStream.on('data', (data) => {
      encoding.stdin.push(data);
    });

    jpegStream.on('end', () => {
      const now = Date.now();
      const timeSpan = Math.max(refreshRate - (now - lastFeed), 0);
      lastFeed = now;

      setTimeout(feed, timeSpan);
    });
  };

  feed();

  return encoding.stdout;
};

module.exports = require('canvas');
```

Any suggestions on how to make it work?

Comment: related: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1698

Comment: Get the ffmpeg command working before you integrate it into your script. Doing so would have shown you at least one error: `Error parsing framerate image2pipe`, which means you should use `'-f', 'image2pipe',`, not `'-r', 'image2pipe',`.

Comment: Right, I just kept changing the parameters and copied the wrong version. I've updated my code snippet